# Building ArcGIS with bower, node, grunt

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am struggling with setting up arcgis javascript api locally.
Tried following https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/get-api/index.html#using-bower-for-local-builds but no use. No help from sample application https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources.git

- Bower installs arcgis-js-api
- I setup a dojoConfig file
- npm install
- bower install
- grunt build => FAIL

  > Error: Cannot find module "src/dojo/dojo.js"

how is it supposed to work since bower installed packages are not npm ready. cannot be dynamically loaded. Whiskey Tango Foxtrot.
please help.

Tried a yeoman generator *arcgis-js-app* still no good. I get the same error **/sampleapp/src/dojo/dojo.js" Error (404): "Not found"**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with the sample application as is (i.e. you're not modifying it yet), then it sounds like your bower install failed. Under `src` you should see folders like `esri` and `dojo` - if they are not there, then the bower install did not complete.

Comment: Hi. actually bower install is good. I can see folders "esri" "dojo" "dgrid" ..etc

Comment: [correction] why would bower install under src? bower would install in bower_components. src/dojo.js should be a built version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Dojo like :

```
  var dojoConfig = {
  baseUrl: '.',
  packages: [
  {
    name: 'dgrid',
    location: 'bower_components/dgrid',
  },
  {
    name: 'dijit',
    location: 'bower_components/dijit',
  },
  {
    name: 'dojo',
    location: 'bower_components/dojo',
  },
  {
    name: 'dojox',
    location: 'bower_components/dojox',
  },
  {
    name: 'dstore',
    location: 'bower_components/dstore',
  },
  {
    name: 'esri',
    location: 'bower_components/esri',
  },
  {
    name: 'put-selector',
    location: 'bower_components/put-selector',
  },
  {
    name: 'xstyle',
    location: 'bower_components/xstyle',
  }
  ]
  };
```

or configure bower (in .bowerrc):

```
{
"directory":"src/"
}
```

Source: [official documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_bower_custom_builds.html#get-started).